# How to create a loop inside a loop vba

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to create this loop inside the loop so as to print inside the cells in the below range -> Week `i` where `i` is from 1 to 6 and it raises by one each time we move to a cell down...

So, in this case, for `D2` I want Week 1, For `D3` Week 2 etc.. Any ideas? I appreciate your time!

```
 Sub INPUT()
        Sheets("1").Select 
        For Each cell In range("D2:D7")
        For i = 1 To 6
        cell.Value = "Week +" & i
        i = i + 1
        Next i
        Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: The answer below obviously gives you the code you need.  But purely as a FYI, the problem with your code above is that you don't need the `i=i+1`.  The incrementing is managed by the `For i = 1 to 6' and 'next i'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need the one loop:

```
Sub INPT()
    With Sheets("1")
        i = 1
        For Each cell In .Range("D2:D7")
            cell.Value = "Week +" & i
            i = i + 1
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i starts counting from 0.. can I make it start from 1 because first week appears as Week + (empty)